# Using a custom rbf kernel function for sklearn's SVC is way faster than built-in method

Tags: python, performance, scikit-learn, svm

I've noticed a rather peculiar but potentially very useful phenomenon when using **Scikit-Learn's SVC** implementation. Using the **built-in rbf kernel** with SVC is **slower** by magnitudes than passing a **custom rbf function to SVC()**.

From what I could see and understand so far, the only difference between the two versions is that **in the built-in rbf case, not sklearn but libsvm will compute the kernel**. Passing a dedicated kernel function as hyperparameter to SVC() leads to the computation of the kernel inside sklearn, not in libsvm. The results are identical, but **the latter case takes only a fraction of the computation time**.

## Example

I've included an example so that you can replicate this behavior.

I've created a toy dataset that mimics the data I am currently working on. By the way, I also work on data with around a thousand samples but high dimensionality (~50000 features). This results in pretty much the same behavior.

```
import numpy as np
from time import time
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import rbf_kernel
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

# create toy data
n_features = 1000
n_samples = 10000
n_informative = 10
X, y = make_classification(n_samples, n_features, n_informative=n_informative)
gamma = 1 / n_features
```

#### Built-in RBF

First, let's fit an SVC using the built-in 'rbf' kernel. This is probably the way people usually run an SVC.

```
# fit SVC with built-in rbf kernel
svc_built_in = SVC(kernel='rbf', gamma=gamma)
np.random.seed(13)
t1 = time()
svc_built_in.fit(X, y)
acc = accuracy_score(y, svc_built_in.predict(X))
print("Fitting SVC with built-in kernel took {:.1f} seconds".format(time()-t1))
print("Accuracy: {}".format(acc))
```

#### Custom RBF function

Second, let's do the same thing only passing the rbf kernel function of sklearn which should do exactly the same.

```
# fit SVC with custom rbf kernel
svc_custom = SVC(kernel=rbf_kernel, gamma=gamma)
np.random.seed(13)
t1 = time()
svc_custom.fit(X, y)
acc = accuracy_score(y, svc_custom.predict(X))
print("Fitting SVC with a custom kernel took {:.1f} seconds".format(time()-t1))
print("Accuracy: {}".format(acc))
```

#### Results

This will give the following result.

```
Fitting SVC with built-in kernel took 58.6 seconds
Accuracy: 0.9846
Fitting SVC with a custom kernel took 3.2 seconds
Accuracy: 0.9846
```

## My question

1. Does anyone have an idea why passing a kernel function is so much faster than using libsvm's kernel computation?
2. For my specific use case (usually large datasets and long computation time), this actually is super useful as I can run many more hyperparameter settings using the second method since the computation time is so significantly decreased. Any reasons not to do this?

Comment: This would make a lot more sense as a bug report in [sklearn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Bug%3A+triage&template=bug_report.yml)

Comment: Makes sense... Here's the issue I've created on sklearn's Github page https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/21410

Answer (score 1):

I have received some good answers to this question on the sklearn bug report (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/21410) so I thought I'd share this knowledge here.

Apparently, the computation of the kernel within sklearn (and not libsvm) is done using numpy. Numpy, however, automatically uses all available threads on your machine to speed up the kernel computation. As I was running this analysis on a machine with 32 threads, I was seeing a dramatic performance increase. Not sure if there are other reasons for numpy being faster (faster or smarter memory access or something like that) but I can definitely confirm the parallelization happening.

So, my take on this is, if you are running SVC on a larger dataset and can make use of multiple threads on your machine, it might be worthwhile to pass the kernel function itself and not merely a string specifier to the SVC instance. All standard kernel functions are already implemented in sklearn in `metrics.pairwise` (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/metrics.html).